# Visual Studio use clang compiler and fails

Tags: c++, clang

I have a strange problem with Visual Studio. Yesterday, all was fine.  Today, it gives me compiler errors, even if i try to run just an example like this:

```
int main()
{
 return 0;
}
```

This is all of the errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C4335   Mac file format detected: please convert the source file to either DOS or UNIX format   test    c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe   1   
Error   C3872   '0x90': this character is not allowed in an identifier  test    c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe   1   
Error   C2018   unknown character '0x3' test    c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe   1   
Error   C2018   unknown character '0x4' test    c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe   1   
Error   C2018   unknown character '0x40'    test    c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe   1   
Error   C2018   unknown character '0x18'    test    c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe   1   
Error   C2018   unknown character '0x1' test    c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe   1   
Error   C2018   unknown character '0xe' test    c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe   1   
Error   C2018   unknown character '0x1f'    test    c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe   1   
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    test    c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe   1   
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'ÿÿ¸'   test    c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe   1   
Error   C3872   '0x2021': this character is not allowed in an identifier    test    c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe   2   
Error   C2018   unknown character '0x1d'    test    c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe   2   
Error   C3872   '0xa9': this character is not allowed in an identifier  test    c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe   2   
Error   C3873   '0xa9': this character is not allowed as a first character of an identifier test    c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe   2   
Error   C3872   '0xf7': this character is not allowed in an identifier  test    c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe   2   
Error   C2018   unknown character '0x6' test    c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe   2   
Error   C2018   unknown character '0x16'    test    c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe   2   
Error   C2018   unknown character '0x1' test    c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe   2   
Error   C2018   unknown character '0x7' test    c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe   2   
Error   C2018   unknown character '0x2' test    c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe   2   
Error   C2018   unknown character '0xe' test    c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe   2
```

This is happening even if I create an empty project.

I think the problem is related with `clang.exe` from Qt. I don't understand why it is trying to use that compiler (I didn't change anything).

How can I change this and use the "Visual C++ 14.1" compiler again?

Comment: Change toolset in project settings.

Comment: I have done this already (is Visual Studio 2017 (v141)) and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> Below are some solutions might help you.

1. You can delete your bin and obj folder then try to build
2. Clean your solution then build your project
3. Move your project from C to D drive (Might be some security access problem).
4. Clear your Temp files Win+R -- %Temp% hit enter and remove temp files

Comment: I have tried all you suggested but still doesn't work. Always tries to compile using this path : c:\qt\qt5.9.3\tools\qtcreator\bin\clang\bin\clang.exe

Comment: Is there any package added ? If yes then close visual studio delete packages folder and restore your packages then try again.

Comment: I have removed everything, I have created a new project on a new disk only with main() and the result is the same.

Comment: Restore your visual studio it seems other updates have broken something

Comment: how can I do this?

Comment: I also restore the settings and the result is the same.